# emacs24 Mac - Mouse works but keyboard input stays in terminal

Tags: osx

When I run emacs24 on my Mac, the keyboard input continues to appear in the terminal instead of in the emacs shell.

I just installed emacs on my Mac using Homebrew. eg

```
brew install emacs --cocoa
ln -s /opt/boxen/homebrew/Cellar/emacs/24.3/Emacs.app /Applications
emacs-24.3
```

Loads a graphical version of emacs.  When I mouseover and click things move as expected.  But the keyboard does not. eg I can't type anything in and have the cursor respond.  Instead the keyboard input remains on the terminal.  So if I type right-arrow

^[[C

Appears in terminal...

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure what causes this exactly, but the right way to run Emacs is to

```
$ open /Applications/Emacs.app
```

You might want to setup an alias for this:

```
$ alias emacs='open /Applications/Emacs.app --args "$@"'
```

It looks like homebrew links its emacs binaries outside of the Emacs.app, so that it will probably not work very well in graphical mode. There shouldn't be a problem for running it in console mode though

```
$ emacs-24.3 -nw
```